# Concatenar duas listas estáticas sequenciais

Tags: c, lista

Estou com dificuldade pra fazer uma função que recebe duas listas e retorna uma terceira com os elementos da primeira concatenados com os elementos da segunda. Fiz o código mas ele me retorna a terceira lista com os elementos do primeiro e com lixo de memória ao invés dos elementos do segundo.

```
Lista concatenar(Lista lst1, Lista lst2) {

  Lista lst3 = (Lista) malloc(sizeof(Lista));
  int i,j;

  for (i = 0; i < lst1->fim; i++) {
    lst3->no[i] = lst1->no[i];
  }

  j = lst3->fim;

  for (i = 0; i < lst2->fim; i++) {
    lst3->no[j+1] = lst2->no[i];
  }

  return lst3;
}
```

Chamada do insere(essa função tá funcionando normal):

```
insere_elem(lst1, 4);
insere_elem(lst1, 12);
insere_elem(lst1, 0);

insere_elem(lst2, 11);
insere_elem(lst2, 18);
insere_elem(lst2, 25);
```

Struct lista:

```
struct lista {
  int no[max];
  int fim;
};
```

Comment: Poste a declaração de sua variável Lista. Você diz que é uma lista estática sequencial mas pelo tratamento dá a impressão de ser uma lista dinâmica encadeada.

Comment: Fiz isso, adicionei a struct o meu código

Comment: primeiro você precisa fazer esse programa compilar...porque do jeito que você colocou ele simplesmente não compila...

Comment: Você não está usando lista ligada, mas sim um vetor. Por que chama essa região contígua de memória de lista?

Answer (score 0):

Já que você estava utilizando ponteiros precisei fazer algumas alteraçoes, onde sem tais eu nao enxergo como o codigo funcionaria...Você tem um "TL", controlador, embutido na struct, o "FIM"...use ele.
Ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define max 100

struct lista {
  int no[max];
  int fim;
};typedef struct lista Lista;

void init(Lista ** lst)
{
    *lst = (Lista*) malloc (sizeof(Lista));     
    (*lst) -> fim = 0;
}
Lista* concatenar(Lista * lst1, Lista * lst2) {
  Lista * lst;
  init(&lst);

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < lst1->fim; i++) {
    lst->no[lst -> fim] = lst1->no[i];
    lst -> fim++;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < lst2->fim; i++) {
    lst->no[lst -> fim] = lst2->no[i];
    lst -> fim++;
  }

  return lst;
}


void insere_elem(Lista ** lst, int elem)
{
    if((*lst) -> fim <= max)
    {
        (*lst) -> no[(*lst) -> fim] = elem;
        (*lst) -> fim++;
    }   
}



void exibeLista(Lista * lst)
{
    for(int i=0; i < lst -> fim; i++)
        printf("%d ", lst -> no[i]);        
    printf("\n\n\n\n");

}

int main(void)
{
    Lista * lst1;
    init(&lst1);
    Lista * lst2;
    init(&lst2);

    Lista * lst3;


    insere_elem(&lst1, 4);
    insere_elem(&lst1, 12);
    insere_elem(&lst1, 0);

    insere_elem(&lst2, 11);
    insere_elem(&lst2, 18);
    insere_elem(&lst2, 25);

    exibeLista(lst1);
    exibeLista(lst2);

    lst3 = concatenar(lst1, lst2);
    exibeLista(lst3);
    getch();


}
```

Comment: `insere_elem` não deveria receber um ponteiro de um ponteiro da lista, já que não há interesse em se permutar o objeto passado por ponteiro por um outro objeto. Sem falar que o código fica mais limpo sem perder em nada de processamento/abstração

Comment: Pelo seu código, também, seria mais enxuto se você, no lugar de fazer o `for` das duas listas fazendo os passos da função `insere_elem`, chamar logo `insere_elem`. Há um esquema bem melhor em termos de eficiência, mas não é fazendo a "inserção" um-a-um dos elementos